# watch command messes up NVDIA-smi

Tags: watch, nvidia-smi

Im using a cluster and trying to monitor my gpu ussage.
the command I'm using is:

```
srun --jobid 'jobid' watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```

This then creates an output that looks like this:
[Broken Borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IiZn.png)

As you can see the borders are all messed up.

I then ran the same code just wihtout the watch part:

```
srun --jobid 'jobid' nvidia-smi
```

and then the out put was good and looked like this:
[Normal Borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTQv7.png)

I doesnt really bother me all that much since I can still tell how much gpu I am using, but I'm just a bit curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Perhaps related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/prevent-watch-breaking-colors)? Would something like `while sleep 0.5; do tput reset; nvidia-smi; done` work for you?